# Finding an element of a certain order in a commutative group.

Tags: group-theory

Suppose that $G$ is commutative and that the prime $p$ divides the order of $G$. 
Using (i) and (ii) prove that $G$ contains an element of order $p$. (You may not use Sylow’s Theorem.)

A,B are subgroups.
In the previous parts: (i) I have proved that $AB = \{ab : a \in A, b \in B\}$ is a group if and only if $AB = BA$. Given an example of $A, B \subseteq G$ where $AB$ is not a group and proved this. And (ii) stated a formula for the number of elements in $AB$: supposing that $|G| = |A||B|$ and that $|A|$ and $|B|$ are co-prime, proved that $G = AB$.

I have the following theorem in my notes: Let $G$ be a finite abelian group of order $n$ and let $k$ divide $n$. Then $G$ has a subgroup of order $k$. I think it could be using this, but I have no proof for this theorem.

Thank you.

Comment: Are $A$ and $B$ assumed to be subgroups here?

Comment: yes, sorry will edit it now.

Comment: Hint: Assume it does not hold and let $G$ be a minimal counter example. Can $G$ have a proper subgroup whose order is divisible by $p$? What then happens if you take two distinct maximal subgroups and look at their product?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft, I'm not sure i understand your hint, could you please elaborate?

Comment: Do you see the first part? What happens if a proper subgroup has order divisible by $p$?

Comment: it can't have a proper subgroup whose order is divisible by p, i know it, but can't remember exactly why.

Comment: You should not try to remember. You should try to deduce it. It might help if you write up precisely what it is we are assuming about $G$ for it to be a minimal counterexample.

Comment: we assume that the prime p doesn't divide the order of G?

Comment: No, if $p$ does not divide the order of $G$ then there is no way $G$ could be a counterexample to the statement.

Comment: oh i am very confused then

Comment: Ok, let's ignore the "minimal" part for now and focus on what it would take for a group to be a counterexample. So the statement is that if $p$ divides the order of $G$ then $G$ has a subgroup of order $p$. So what properties are needed for a counterexample?

Comment: if p divides the order of G then G doesn't have a subgroup of order p?

Comment: Not quite. How do you negate "x implies y" in general?

Comment: this is so stupid i don't know why i don't get it. x doesn't imply y?

Comment: Well, yes, but more precisely: It is possible to ave x but not y. So for the group, we assume that $p$ divides the order but that $G$ does not have a subgroup of order $p$.

Comment: oh of course, that is really stupid of me. okay, so then we prove that in fact to have p dividing the order of G then G must have a subgroup of order p?